# access and set variables in a class from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, variables, partial-classes

i'v a shopping_cart.aspx.cs file & also have a class file spcart.cs,

**shopping_cart.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Ui_ShoppingCart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int tax = 0;   
    public int subtotal = 0;
    public int granttotal = 0;  

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             -------------------------/////some code
         }
   --------------------------------/////some code
}
```

**spcart.cs**

```
public class Spcart
    {     
        public void updatecart(int pid,int qty)
         {
             ---------/////some code
         }
    }
```

now i want to set some values in `class Ui_ShoppingCart` variables tax, subtoal & granttotals from class Spcart, so i'd tried-->

```
Ui_ShoppingCart.tax
```

but it didnt worked.........
is there any other way to set these variables ???
can anyone help me about this???

Comment: Create an instance of the class whose properties you want to use.

Comment: The instance of the page already exists, you don't have to create it. Which object owns the instance of Spcart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be the other way round

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SpCart cart = new SpCart();
   cart.updateCart(124, 4);

   tax = cart.getComputedTax();
   subTotal = cart.getSubTotal();
   ...
}
```

The idea is those variables should independent of your SpCart code.

```
public class Spcart
{     
     public void updatecart(int pid,int qty)
     {
         ---------/////some code
     }

     public int getComputedTax()
     {
       //can compute tax here
       int tax = whatever;
       return tax;
     }
}
```

The computation logics can still be separated into some other class

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access "tax" property declared in "Ui_ShoppingCart" from "Spcart" class. It is not possible to do it. Instead you have to pass them as additional parameters to updatecart method.

```
Spcart cart = new Spcart();
cart.updatecart(pid,qty,tax);
```

Or if tax is used in other methods of the "spcart" class, initialize it in the contructor.

```
public class Spcart
{     
 private int _tax = 0;
 public Spcart(int tax)
 {
   _tax = tax;
 }
 public void updatecart(int pid,int qty)
 {
    int amount = qty + _tax;
 }
}
```

And call using

```
Spcart cart = new Spcart(tax);
cart.updatecart(pid,qty);
```